# VB.Net: Retrieve input and display in upper and lower cases

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Say I have a textbox that has the following text : "hello" without the quotes. How would I take that text and output something like this : [Hh][Ee][Ll][Ll][Oo]

Is there a better/faster way than manually changing it?

Comment: so you want the output to look exactly like this>>>  [Hh][Ee][Ll][Ll][Oo]?

Comment: Yeah, that's how I want it to look like. From "hello" to [Hh][Ee][Ll][Ll][Oo]

I tried to read the text 1 letter at a time but I'm not sure how to turn it into [Xx], unless I manually type it in

Comment: check my answer if it is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is more in a logic part.

Providing you have a `textbox` and a `button` that when you click the button, the output will pop in a message box... just use substring and convert each character to `uppercase` and `lowercase` and simply add the brackets like this

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim input As String = TextBox1.Text.Trim
    Dim output As String = ""
    For index As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1
        output += "[" + input.Substring(index, 1).ToUpper + "" + input.Substring(index, 1).ToLower + "]"
    Next
    MsgBox(output)
End Sub
End Class
```

> from here below is the code added by Niranjan Kala. The code is not in vb but try to convert it.

//It would be better if you use StringBuilder rather than using SubString Method to create new strings in memory to append in output..See below code snippet:

```
string message ="hello"; // = TextBox1.Text.Trim()
StringBuilder br = new StringBuilder();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
{
    char[] charArray = message.ToArray();
    for(int index = 0;index< charArray.Length;index++)
    {
        br.AppendFormat("[{0}{1}]", Char.ToUpper(charArray[index]), Char.ToLower(charArray[index]));
    }
}
string result = br.ToString();
result.Dump();
```

Comment: Wow, I forgot Visual studio had a upper and lowercase class. I need to keep reading...Thank you though!

Comment: @DavidSo: *Visual Studio* does not have a upper and lower case class. It's an IDE. If something would have such classes at all, it would be the .NET *framework class library*. But even that does not have *classes* for upper and lower casing -- the `System.Char` and `System.String` classes have *methods* for such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Function ReBuildStr(s As String) As String
    Dim result As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    For Each c As Char In s
        result.AppendFormat("[{0}{1}]", Char.ToUpper(c), Char.ToLower(c))
    Next

    Return result.ToString()
End Function
```

Or if you don't want to use `StringBuilder` you can use a `String` using this inside the `For`:

```
result &= "[" & Char.ToUpper(c) & Char.ToLower(c) & "]"
```